# jasper report using iReport : Spanning multiple pages, page size A4

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a Jasper report designed using iReport to have 6 fix sized 6X6 blocks placed vertically below the other.

The problem is that the length of these combined blocks (header + footer + these blocks) exceeds that of A4 sheet size. So when these are printed on an A4 sheet the font is reduced to a very small size making the entire report almost unreadable.

I have tried seperating half the blocks in two seperate detail bands. But it results in the same problem (small font) even if half blocks appear on 1st page and rest on 2nd page.

(Probably due to the large content required in a single layout the size of the jrxml page has gone beyond that of A4 page)

What should I do to have the report output split across multiple pages retaining its normal font size and that too on an A4 sheet ??

Thanks

Comment: Use summary band in place of detail band because detail band split report in multiple pages depend on query rows.

Comment: OR - could you please each block in its own detail band?

Comment: What is the split type for the band that holds the 6x6 blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks :)

Using own detail band got me almost to the solution.
However I am still stuck at another point.

If data of all the bands is to be displayed simultaneously then the bands split over multiple pages as I want.

But if the data of only one band is to be displayed then an empty page at the end of the report is displayed with a footer ("page 2 of 2"). However the data is only on 1st page ("page 1 of 2").

Any ideas how do I eliminate this extra last page ?

Thanks